# How to exclude last line from scraped content in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
content = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="content"]/p')
```

Now there is a list of paragraphs that were scraped, like- content[0],content[1].....content[9]
The number of paragraph is not fixed everytime, I want to delete the last paragraph from the content.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question with some more details, so that everybody could understand and reproduce your issue easily. Also take a minute to read [ask] - Would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list slicing` to keep everything except the last item:

```
content = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="content"]/p')[:-1]
```